# Accessing AngularJS View from JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to access AngularJS view from JQuery. Below are my codes. Appreciate your help on this. I believe it is something to do with DOM manipulation which created by AngularJS using ng-bind but I'm not sure how to fix this. TQ.

[html]

```
<div class="row" ng-app="ProjectApp" ng-controller="ProjectController">
  <span id="ajaxPath">{{ajaxPath}}</span>
<div>
```

[controller] - set ajaxPath value

```
angular.module('ProjectApp')
.controller('ProjectController', function($scope){
   $scope.ajaxPath = "http://localhost:8080/api/projectlist";
});
```

[jquery] - get ajaxPath value

```
console.log($('#ajaxPath').text());
//output = {{ajaxPath}}
```

Comment: but its working alreay the console is printing https://plnkr.co/edit/JNdD9n0I4oAOLuI3LFXn?p=preview

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to accomplish? This approach is considered anti-pattern in AngularJs, but if you explain what you are trying to do maybe we can help you do it in some other way :)

Comment: thanks gayathri. FYI, there're 3 different files involve - html file, js file (angular) and js file (jquery). my intention is to get the value assign from the controller to {{ajaxPath}} and get this value inside another js (jquery). this is due to legacy code that being written in JQuery. So, I still need to use this JQuery file and update the value whisch being set by angularjs controller. Hope that clear up the scenario.

Comment: Would you consider creating a shared object at window level? `$scope.ajaxPath = "..."; $window.prj.common.ajaxPath = $scope.ajaxPath;`

Comment: This is not a good approach but you can access scope vars as `angular.element($('#ajaxPath')).scope().ajaxPath`. But I think you won't be able to access it on production.